# Returning result in R

Tags: r

I have a 1 X 1000 vector = x of numbers from 1 to 1000, and a certain function = y into which I plug in these numbers, resulting in a 1 x 1000 vector of results. I would like for R to return the value of y at which the function is greater than a certain number. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 res[ which(res > threshold)[1] ] #........
```

Comment: doesn't this return the value of x at which y is above the threshold? But the question asks for the value of y ... (or does it?), also this will be the FIRST value of x at which y is above the threshold. It's a really ambiguous question actually.

Comment: I edited it to be the y-value under assumption  that `res` was `f(x)`, but agree it is unclear exactly what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the result from function y `res`

```
res_over_certain_number <- res[res > certain_number]
```